# I want to parameterize API collection

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I have 2 request API in postman now I want to do parameterization for them  through CSV file, bit for first request I have 7 rows and for second request I have only 5 rows. And while running collection I have to pass same single CSV for both request, but while running test for second request postman running iteration for 7 time instead of 5, IS there any way that postman can run iteration only for given rows in CSV

Is there any way If I can handle this in postman pre-request script

I want to parameterize my API collection but only with CSV data if row from CSV is empty postman should skip the iteration and jump on another API